# How to include a FX shader to my game?

Tags: c++, shaders, hlsl, directx9

I have an old game source from 2004, the game runs DirectX9, and I want to improve the graphics.

I downloaded NVIDIA FX Composer 2.5, and I created a “`Phong_bump_reflect.fx`”.

I want to add the effect to my terrain, is there any way ?

I tried like this, on the terrain render function:

```
void CMapOutdoor::__RenderTerrain_RenderHardwareTransformPatch()
{
    m_pShader = NULL;
    ms_lpd3dDevice = NULL;

    if (D3DXCreateEffectFromFileA(ms_lpd3dDevice, "Phong_bump_relect.fx", 0, 0, 0, 0, &m_pShader, 0) != S_OK)
        assert(!"Failed to create shader !");

    DWORD dwFogColor;
    float fFogFarDistance;
    float fFogNearDistance;
    if (mc_pEnvironmentData)
    {
        dwFogColor = mc_pEnvironmentData->FogColor;
#ifdef ENABLE_MODE_HD

        if (ActiveHD)
        {
            fFogNearDistance = mc_pEnvironmentData->GetFogNearDistance() * 5;
            fFogFarDistance = mc_pEnvironmentData->GetFogFarDistance() * 5;
        }
        else
        {
            fFogNearDistance = mc_pEnvironmentData->GetFogNearDistance();
            fFogFarDistance = mc_pEnvironmentData->GetFogFarDistance();
        }
#else
        fFogNearDistance = mc_pEnvironmentData->GetFogNearDistance();
        fFogFarDistance = mc_pEnvironmentData->GetFogFarDistance();
#endif
    }
    else
    {
        dwFogColor = 0xffffffff;
        fFogNearDistance = 5000.0f;
        fFogFarDistance = 10000.0f;
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Render State & TextureStageState 

    STATEMANAGER.SaveTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_TEXCOORDINDEX, D3DTSS_TCI_CAMERASPACEPOSITION);
    STATEMANAGER.SaveTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_TEXTURETRANSFORMFLAGS, D3DTTFF_COUNT2);
    STATEMANAGER.SaveTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_TEXCOORDINDEX, D3DTSS_TCI_CAMERASPACEPOSITION);
    STATEMANAGER.SaveTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_TEXTURETRANSFORMFLAGS, D3DTTFF_COUNT2);

    STATEMANAGER.SaveRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, TRUE);
    STATEMANAGER.SaveRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHATESTENABLE, TRUE);
    STATEMANAGER.SaveRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHAREF, 0x00000000);
    STATEMANAGER.SaveRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHAFUNC, D3DCMP_GREATER);

    STATEMANAGER.SaveRenderState(D3DRS_TEXTUREFACTOR, dwFogColor);

    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG2, D3DTA_CURRENT);
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_MODULATE);
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
#ifdef DIRECTX9
    STATEMANAGER.SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_ADDRESSU, D3DTADDRESS_WRAP);
    STATEMANAGER.SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_ADDRESSV, D3DTADDRESS_WRAP);
#else
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ADDRESSU, D3DTADDRESS_WRAP);
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ADDRESSV, D3DTADDRESS_WRAP);
#endif

    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_CURRENT);
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
#ifdef DIRECTX9
    STATEMANAGER.SetSamplerState(1, D3DSAMP_ADDRESSU, D3DTADDRESS_CLAMP);
    STATEMANAGER.SetSamplerState(1, D3DSAMP_ADDRESSV, D3DTADDRESS_CLAMP);
#else
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_ADDRESSU, D3DTADDRESS_CLAMP);
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_ADDRESSV, D3DTADDRESS_CLAMP);
#endif

#ifdef WORLD_EDITOR
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CAPITAL))
    {
        CSpeedTreeWrapper::ms_bSelfShadowOn = false;
        STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_MINFILTER, D3DTEXF_GAUSSIANCUBIC);
        STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_MAGFILTER, D3DTEXF_GAUSSIANCUBIC);
        STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_MIPFILTER, D3DTEXF_GAUSSIANCUBIC);
        STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_MINFILTER, D3DTEXF_GAUSSIANCUBIC);
        STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_MAGFILTER, D3DTEXF_GAUSSIANCUBIC);
        STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_MIPFILTER, D3DTEXF_GAUSSIANCUBIC);
    }
    else
    {
        CSpeedTreeWrapper::ms_bSelfShadowOn = true;
        STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_MINFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
        STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_MAGFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
        STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_MIPFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
        STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_MINFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
        STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_MAGFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
        STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_MIPFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
    }
#else
    CSpeedTreeWrapper::ms_bSelfShadowOn = true;
    STATEMANAGER.SetBestFiltering(0);
    STATEMANAGER.SetBestFiltering(1);
#endif

    m_matWorldForCommonUse._41 = 0.0f;
    m_matWorldForCommonUse._42 = 0.0f;
    STATEMANAGER.SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &m_matWorldForCommonUse);

    STATEMANAGER.SaveTransform(D3DTS_TEXTURE0, &m_matWorldForCommonUse);
    STATEMANAGER.SaveTransform(D3DTS_TEXTURE1, &m_matWorldForCommonUse);

    // Render State & TextureStageState
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    STATEMANAGER.SetVertexShader(D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_NORMAL);

    m_iRenderedSplatNumSqSum = 0;
    m_iRenderedPatchNum = 0;
    m_iRenderedSplatNum = 0;
    m_RenderedTextureNumVector.clear();

    std::pair<float, long> fog_far(fFogFarDistance + 1600.0f, 0);
    std::pair<float, long> fog_near(fFogNearDistance - 3200.0f, 0);

    std::vector<std::pair<float, long> >::iterator far_it = std::upper_bound(m_PatchVector.begin(), m_PatchVector.end(), fog_far);
    std::vector<std::pair<float, long> >::iterator near_it = std::upper_bound(m_PatchVector.begin(), m_PatchVector.end(), fog_near);

    // NOTE: Word Editor 툴에서는 fog far보다 멀리있는 물체를 텍스쳐 없이 그리는 작업을 하지 않음
#ifdef WORLD_EDITOR
    near_it = m_PatchVector.begin();
    far_it = m_PatchVector.end();
#endif

    WORD wPrimitiveCount;
    D3DPRIMITIVETYPE ePrimitiveType;

    BYTE byCUrrentLODLevel = 0;

    float fLODLevel1Distance = __GetNoFogDistance();
    float fLODLevel2Distance = __GetFogDistance();

#ifdef ENABLE_MODE_HD
    if (ActiveHD)
    {
        float fLODLevel1Distance = __GetNoFogDistance() * 5;
        float fLODLevel2Distance = __GetFogDistance() * 5;
    }
    else
    {
        float fLODLevel1Distance = __GetNoFogDistance();
        float fLODLevel2Distance = __GetFogDistance();
    }
#endif

    SelectIndexBuffer(0, &wPrimitiveCount, &ePrimitiveType);

    DWORD dwFogEnable = STATEMANAGER.GetRenderState(D3DRS_FOGENABLE);
    std::vector<std::pair<float, long> >::iterator it = m_PatchVector.begin();

    // NOTE: 맵툴에서는 view ~ fog near 사이의 지형을 fog disabled 상태로 그리는 작업을 하지 않음.
#ifndef WORLD_EDITOR
    STATEMANAGER.SetRenderState(D3DRS_FOGENABLE, FALSE);

    for (; it != near_it; ++it)
    {
        if (byCUrrentLODLevel == 0 && fLODLevel1Distance <= it->first)
        {
            byCUrrentLODLevel = 1;
            SelectIndexBuffer(1, &wPrimitiveCount, &ePrimitiveType);
        }
        else if (byCUrrentLODLevel == 1 && fLODLevel2Distance <= it->first)
        {
            byCUrrentLODLevel = 2;
            SelectIndexBuffer(2, &wPrimitiveCount, &ePrimitiveType);
        }

        __HardwareTransformPatch_RenderPatchSplat(it->second, wPrimitiveCount, ePrimitiveType);
        if (m_iRenderedSplatNum >= m_iSplatLimit)
            break;

        if (m_bDrawWireFrame)
            DrawWireFrame(it->second, wPrimitiveCount, ePrimitiveType);
    }
#endif

    STATEMANAGER.SetRenderState(D3DRS_FOGENABLE, dwFogEnable);

    if (m_iRenderedSplatNum < m_iSplatLimit)
    {
        for (it = near_it; it != far_it; ++it)
        {
            if (byCUrrentLODLevel == 0 && fLODLevel1Distance <= it->first)
            {
                byCUrrentLODLevel = 1;
                SelectIndexBuffer(1, &wPrimitiveCount, &ePrimitiveType);
            }
            else if (byCUrrentLODLevel == 1 && fLODLevel2Distance <= it->first)
            {
                byCUrrentLODLevel = 2;
                SelectIndexBuffer(2, &wPrimitiveCount, &ePrimitiveType);
            }

            __HardwareTransformPatch_RenderPatchSplat(it->second, wPrimitiveCount, ePrimitiveType);

            if (m_iRenderedSplatNum >= m_iSplatLimit)
                break;

            if (m_bDrawWireFrame)
                DrawWireFrame(it->second, wPrimitiveCount, ePrimitiveType);
        }
    }

    STATEMANAGER.SetRenderState(D3DRS_FOGENABLE, FALSE);
#ifdef ENABLE_MODE_HD
    if (ActiveHD)
    {
        STATEMANAGER.SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, TRUE);
    }
    else
    {
        STATEMANAGER.SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, FALSE);
    }
#else
    STATEMANAGER.SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, FALSE);
#endif

    STATEMANAGER.SetTexture(0, NULL);
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_TEXTURETRANSFORMFLAGS, FALSE);

    STATEMANAGER.SetTexture(1, NULL);
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_TEXTURETRANSFORMFLAGS, FALSE);

    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_TFACTOR);
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_DISABLE);

    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_DISABLE);
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_DISABLE);

    if (m_iRenderedSplatNum < m_iSplatLimit)
    {
        for (it = far_it; it != m_PatchVector.end(); ++it)
        {
            if (byCUrrentLODLevel == 0 && fLODLevel1Distance <= it->first)
            {
                byCUrrentLODLevel = 1;
                SelectIndexBuffer(1, &wPrimitiveCount, &ePrimitiveType);
            }
            else if (byCUrrentLODLevel == 1 && fLODLevel2Distance <= it->first)
            {
                byCUrrentLODLevel = 2;
                SelectIndexBuffer(2, &wPrimitiveCount, &ePrimitiveType);
            }

            __HardwareTransformPatch_RenderPatchNone(it->second, wPrimitiveCount, ePrimitiveType);

            if (m_iRenderedSplatNum >= m_iSplatLimit)
                break;

            if (m_bDrawWireFrame)
                DrawWireFrame(it->second, wPrimitiveCount, ePrimitiveType);
        }
    }

    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG2, D3DTA_CURRENT);
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_MODULATE);
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);

    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_CURRENT);
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
    STATEMANAGER.SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);

    STATEMANAGER.SetRenderState(D3DRS_FOGENABLE, dwFogEnable);
    STATEMANAGER.SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, TRUE);

    std::sort(m_RenderedTextureNumVector.begin(), m_RenderedTextureNumVector.end());

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Render State & TextureStageState

    STATEMANAGER.RestoreRenderState(D3DRS_TEXTUREFACTOR);

    STATEMANAGER.RestoreTransform(D3DTS_TEXTURE0);
    STATEMANAGER.RestoreTransform(D3DTS_TEXTURE1);

    STATEMANAGER.RestoreTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_TEXCOORDINDEX);
    STATEMANAGER.RestoreTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_TEXTURETRANSFORMFLAGS);
    STATEMANAGER.RestoreTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_TEXCOORDINDEX);
    STATEMANAGER.RestoreTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_TEXTURETRANSFORMFLAGS);

    STATEMANAGER.RestoreRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE);
    STATEMANAGER.RestoreRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHATESTENABLE);
    STATEMANAGER.RestoreRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHAREF);
    STATEMANAGER.RestoreRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHAFUNC);

    // Render State & TextureStageState
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

FX Shader:

```
#define FLIP_TEXTURE_Y

float Script : STANDARDSGLOBAL <
    string UIWidget = "none";
    string ScriptClass = "object";
    string ScriptOrder = "standard";
    string ScriptOutput = "color";
    string Script = "Technique=Phong?Main:Main10;";
> = 0.8;

//// UN-TWEAKABLES - AUTOMATICALLY-TRACKED TRANSFORMS ////////////////

float4x4 WorldITXf : WorldInverseTranspose < string UIWidget="None"; >;
float4x4 WvpXf : WorldViewProjection < string UIWidget="None"; >;
float4x4 WorldXf : World < string UIWidget="None"; >;
float4x4 ViewIXf : ViewInverse < string UIWidget="None"; >;

//// TWEAKABLE PARAMETERS ////////////////////

/// Point Lamp 0 ////////////
float3 Lamp0Pos : Position <
    string Object = "PointLight0";
    string UIName =  "Lamp 0 Position";
    string Space = "World";
> = {-0.5f,2.0f,1.25f};
float3 Lamp0Color : Specular <
    string UIName =  "Lamp 0";
    string Object = "Pointlight0";
    string UIWidget = "Color";
> = {1.0f,1.0f,1.0f};

// Ambient Light
float3 AmbiColor : Ambient <
    string UIName =  "Ambient Light";
    string UIWidget = "Color";
> = {0.07f,0.07f,0.07f};

float Ks <
    string UIWidget = "slider";
    float UIMin = 0.0;
    float UIMax = 1.0;
    float UIStep = 0.05;
    string UIName =  "Specular";
> = 0.4;

float SpecExpon : SpecularPower <
    string UIWidget = "slider";
    float UIMin = 1.0;
    float UIMax = 128.0;
    float UIStep = 1.0;
    string UIName =  "Specular Power";
> = 55.0;


float Bump <
    string UIWidget = "slider";
    float UIMin = 0.0;
    float UIMax = 3.0;
    float UIStep = 0.01;
    string UIName =  "Bumpiness";
> = 1.0; 

float Kr <
    string UIWidget = "slider";
    float UIMin = 0.0;
    float UIMax = 1.0;
    float UIStep = 0.01;
    string UIName =  "Reflection Strength";
> = 10.5;

//////// COLOR & TEXTURE /////////////////////

texture ColorTexture : DIFFUSE <
    string ResourceName = "default_color.dds";
    string UIName =  "Diffuse Texture";
    string ResourceType = "2D";
>;

sampler2D ColorSampler = sampler_state {
    Texture = <ColorTexture>;
    FILTER = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    AddressU = Wrap;
    AddressV = Wrap;
}; 

texture NormalTexture  <
    string ResourceName = "default_bump_normal.dds";
    string UIName =  "Normal-Map Texture";
    string ResourceType = "2D";
>;

sampler2D NormalSampler = sampler_state {
    Texture = <NormalTexture>;
    FILTER = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    AddressU = Wrap;
    AddressV = Wrap;
}; 

texture EnvTexture : ENVIRONMENT <
    string ResourceName = "default_reflection.dds";
    string UIName =  "Environment";
    string ResourceType = "Cube";
>;

samplerCUBE EnvSampler = sampler_state {
    Texture = <EnvTexture>;
    FILTER = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    AddressU = Clamp;
    AddressV = Clamp;
    AddressW = Clamp;
};

// shared shadow mapping supported in Cg version

//////// CONNECTOR DATA STRUCTURES ///////////

/* data from application vertex buffer */
struct appdata {
    float3 Position : POSITION;
    float4 UV       : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 Normal   : NORMAL;
    float4 Tangent  : TANGENT0;
    float4 Binormal : BINORMAL0;
};

/* data passed from vertex shader to pixel shader */
struct vertexOutput {
    float4 HPosition    : POSITION;
    float2 UV       : TEXCOORD0;
    // The following values are passed in "World" coordinates since
    //   it tends to be the most flexible and easy for handling
    //   reflections, sky lighting, and other "global" effects.
    float3 LightVec : TEXCOORD1;
    float3 WorldNormal  : TEXCOORD2;
    float3 WorldTangent : TEXCOORD3;
    float3 WorldBinormal : TEXCOORD4;
    float3 WorldView    : TEXCOORD5;
};
 
///////// VERTEX SHADING /////////////////////

/*********** Generic Vertex Shader ******/

vertexOutput std_VS(appdata IN) {
    vertexOutput OUT = (vertexOutput)0;
    OUT.WorldNormal = mul(IN.Normal,WorldITXf).xyz;
    OUT.WorldTangent = mul(IN.Tangent,WorldITXf).xyz;
    OUT.WorldBinormal = mul(IN.Binormal,WorldITXf).xyz;
    float4 Po = float4(IN.Position.xyz,1);
    float3 Pw = mul(Po,WorldXf).xyz;
    OUT.LightVec = (Lamp0Pos - Pw);
#ifdef FLIP_TEXTURE_Y
    OUT.UV = float2(IN.UV.x,(1.0-IN.UV.y));
#else /* !FLIP_TEXTURE_Y */
    OUT.UV = IN.UV.xy;
#endif /* !FLIP_TEXTURE_Y */
    OUT.WorldView = normalize(ViewIXf[3].xyz - Pw);
    OUT.HPosition = mul(Po,WvpXf);
    return OUT;
}

///////// PIXEL SHADING //////////////////////

// Utility function for phong shading

void phong_shading(vertexOutput IN,
            float3 LightColor,
            float3 Nn,
            float3 Ln,
            float3 Vn,
            out float3 DiffuseContrib,
            out float3 SpecularContrib)
{
    float3 Hn = normalize(Vn + Ln);
    float4 litV = lit(dot(Ln,Nn),dot(Hn,Nn),SpecExpon);
    DiffuseContrib = litV.y * LightColor;
    SpecularContrib = litV.y * litV.z * Ks * LightColor;
}

float4 std_PS(vertexOutput IN) : COLOR {
    float3 diffContrib;
    float3 specContrib;
    float3 Ln = normalize(IN.LightVec);
    float3 Vn = normalize(IN.WorldView);
    float3 Nn = normalize(IN.WorldNormal);
    float3 Tn = normalize(IN.WorldTangent);
    float3 Bn = normalize(IN.WorldBinormal);
    float3 bump = Bump * (tex2D(NormalSampler,IN.UV).rgb - float3(0.5,0.5,0.5));
    Nn = Nn + bump.x*Tn + bump.y*Bn;
    Nn = normalize(Nn);
    phong_shading(IN,Lamp0Color,Nn,Ln,Vn,diffContrib,specContrib);
    float3 diffuseColor = tex2D(ColorSampler,IN.UV).rgb;
    float3 result = specContrib+(diffuseColor*(diffContrib+AmbiColor));
    float3 R = -reflect(Vn,Nn);
    float3 reflColor = Kr * texCUBE(EnvSampler,R.xyz).rgb;
    result += diffuseColor*reflColor;
    return float4(result,1);
}

///// TECHNIQUES /////////////////////////////
RasterizerState DisableCulling
{
    CullMode = NONE;
};

DepthStencilState DepthEnabling
{
    DepthEnable = TRUE;
};

BlendState DisableBlend
{
    BlendEnable[0] = FALSE;
};

technique10 Main10 <
    string Script = "Pass=p0;";
> {
    pass p0 <
    string Script = "Draw=geometry;";
    > {
        SetVertexShader( CompileShader( vs_4_0, std_VS() ) );
        SetGeometryShader( NULL );
        SetPixelShader( CompileShader( ps_4_0, std_PS() ) );
                
        SetRasterizerState(DisableCulling);       
        SetDepthStencilState(DepthEnabling, 0);
        SetBlendState(DisableBlend, float4( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ), 0xFFFFFFFF);
    }
}

technique Main <
    string Script = "Pass=p0;";
> {
    pass p0 <
    string Script = "Draw=geometry;";
    > {
        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 std_VS();
        ZEnable = true;
        ZWriteEnable = true;
        ZFunc = LessEqual;
        AlphaBlendEnable = false;
        CullMode = None;
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_a std_PS();
    }
}
```

But nothing happened.
I want to create a reflective terrain.

Comment: Since you have the source, have you considered updating the code to Directx11 and shader model 5? It's my understanding that `.fx` and Effect Files are obsolete.

Comment: Yea, I considered. I already upgraded the source from DirectX8 to DirectX9, that was easy since 8 and 9 are very similar. From 9 to 11 will be difficult, because there are so many differences and I don't think I'm capable yet.